# How do I prevent an Asus Q301LA laptop from shutting down when I am actually selecting sleep?

Tags: laptop, sleep, power-management, asus-laptop

I purchased an [Asus Q301LA](http://www.asus.com/supportonly/Q301LA/) laptop about 9 months ago. It ran Windows 8.1 from the beginning, and worked flawlessly.

But about a week ago it began having sleep issues. Whenever I try to put it into sleep mode—whether from the Windows sleep button on the menu or just by closing the lid—it automatically shuts down.

I’ve tried all of the solutions I could find so far:

- Disabling IPv6.
- Uninstalling Asus Power4Gear.
- Creating a new power plan
- Changing every advanced power setting; I have always had closing lid set to “sleep”).

Not only that, but it isn’t just a problem with Windows; I’ve since completely wiped the drive and installed Linux Mint, but the problem remains.

Here is the process:

1. I select sleep in the OS; happens with both operating systems and both sleep modes, S2 and S3.
2. The screen goes black; sometimes in Linux it flashes the login screen once, then goes under.
3. When I hit the power button again—or open the lid—it has restarted.

Because of this I’m not quite sure if the issue is the PC shutting down initially or shutting down when it wakes. Because it’'s happening with both operating systems, I’ve concluded that it could be a BIOS issue, which would make sense given that I was tweaking some settings days before the issue came up.

However even after changing almost every setting available and resetting to “optimized defaults” multiple times there is no difference. From what I’ve found it might be related to some Windows/Asus features such as hybrid sleep/instant on or fast startup. However I’m not sure if those would affect just the os or the whole system, because there aren’t any options in BIOS to change them.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the BIOS. You can find the latest versions here: https://www.asus.com/supportonly/Q301LA/HelpDesk_BIOS/

Updating it worked for me.